# Why can't I erase characters in a string using str.erase(str.begin() + index) in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string

The split function is to erase the characters in a string except for letters and spaces. And then split it into words and store them in a vector. 
like this
input: apple isnot4me
output: "apple" "isnotme"

But `phase.erase(phase.begin() + index);` seems not to work.

Here's my program in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const string ALPHABET("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ");

void split(vector<string> &words, const string &phase)
{
    int pos = 0, size = 0, index = 0;

    //erace the chracters except for letters and spaces
    while((index = phase.find_first_not_of(ALPHABET, pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        phase.erase(phase.begin() + index);
        pos = index;
    }

    pos = 0, size = 0, index = 0; //initialize again

    while((index = phase.find_first_of(" ", pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        size = index - pos;
        words.push_back(phase.substr(pos, size));
        pos = index + 1;
    }

    //add the last word(if exists) to the vector words
    size = phase.length() - pos;
    words.push_back(phase.substr(pos, size));
}
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    string str;

    cin >> str;

    split(words, str);

    int size = words.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "\"" << words[i] << "\"" << ' ';
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I tried  str.erase(str.begin() + index) independently in another program,
like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str("Hello world!");
    int index = str.find_first_of(" ", 0);
    str.erase(str.begin() + index);

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And it works!

Comment: The code as  shown doesn't compile. `phase` is passed in as a `const&`. As such, you can't modify it. Or is that what you meant by "doesn't work"?

Comment: THX!!! THAT'S IS IT!! DEBUGGING FOR HOURS!!

Comment: kexanie: You can't really *debug* something that doesn't *compile*

Comment: @kexanie Next time, make sure to be specific about what "doesn't work". Compilation error, linker error, output doesn't match expectations, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass phase as a **const** string:

```
void split(vector<string> &words, const string &phase)
```

What is surprising is that you can compile because erase is not const... (not supposed to be)